# R - Accesing Google Big Query with R. Authetication failed

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I am trying to access Google Big Query with R, using the 'assertthat' and 'bigrquery' packages, following these instructions:

http://thinktostart.com/using-google-bigquery-with-r/#comment-22450

http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/06/25/google-analytics-data-mining-bigquery-r/

The issue comes at the authentication step, I get directed to a code in the webbrowser, and when I paste the code in the terminal the following error appears:

```
Enter authorization code: 
####CODE GOES HERE#####
Error en function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Could not resolve host: accounts.google.com
```

I think that one possible issue is that we are behind a corporate firewall. While we do have access to the internet and I can install R packages, if I ping google.com from the terminal, I get an error. But I would like to know if any of you have found a solution to this kind of problem.

Thank you very much for reading this post. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the issue. It was related to the corporate proxies. If I use the wifi for visitors I can run queries.